# unable to load header file through sub-folders in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

unable to load header file.
Structure of my codeigniter

Views->dashboard/admin_dashboard/dashboard.php

Controllers->dashboard.php

Now i have header in
Views->header/admin_header/header.php

I have tried with < ?php include('../../header/admin_header/header.php'); ?>

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't do `include`, try load view instead:

```
$this->load->view( 'header/admin_header/header' );
```

**How about making subfolder for controller?**

Here what you should do:

```
Ex:
controllers
    - test
        -- Main.php
```

Then you should regist it on `config/routes.php`, just add on newline:

```
$route['test/(:any)'] = 'test/$1';
```

Now you can access all controller files inside folder `test`

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I know, this is BETTER  than we do `include` or `require`.(Using APPPATH or BASEPATH).

Comment: I am also trying to put controller in sub-folders where all i need to change,here also facing similar issue.

Comment: How about you url? To access it your url must be like this: `http://your_site_url/admin/dashboard`

Comment: controllers->admin->dashboard.php and i have added  
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1'; to routes.php but views are not getting loaded .

Comment: localhost/your_site_url       itself not loading  and if i run as http://your_site_url/admin/dashboard it routs to localhost/your_site_url

Comment: Yes, `your_site_url` means your domain or ip address. If you're in local, it should be `localhost`. Btw, that's odd. I've tested myself, and it works. `

Comment: Have you set `base_url` on `config/config.php`? It should contain your project url. Ex: Inside `xampp/htdocs` I have `myproject`. So I set it to `http://localhost/myproject`. Finally, to access the controller, I should go to `http://localhost/myproject/admin/dashboard`.

Comment: Maybe you don't remove `index.php` on url yet. Try set `base_url` to `http://localhost/myproject/index.php`. Then, access it by `http://localhost/myproject/index.php/admin/dashboard`